# Understanding C++ syntax for array pointers double brackets

Tags: c++

I writing a script which receives a structure (Evt) which holds an array of pointers `uint16_t *DataChannel[Evt->ChSize[ch]]`. I can then loop over the data and print out of the value as so:

```
for(uint16_t ch=0; ch<sizeof(Evt->DataChannel)/sizeof(Evt->DataChannel[0]); ++ch){                                                                                       
 for(int adc_it=0; adc_it<(Evt->ChSize[ch]); ++adc_it){                                                                                                                                                                                    for(int adc_it=0; adc_it<(Evt->ChSize[ch]); ++adc_it){                                                                                                                 
       std::cout << (Evt->DataChannel)[ch][adc_it] << " ";                                                                                                                  
    }    
 }
```

I don't understand  where the second bracket comes from ([adc_it]), what it is doing and how it works. I think (`Evt->DataChannel`) should be a `uint16_t` which is not an array so why the second bracket?

I tried to replicate this in a quick piece of code:

```
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int* test[10];
   *(test[0]) = 5;

   std::cout << test[0][0] << std::endl;  //Gives 5 
   std::cout << test[0][1] << std::endl;  //Seg faults

   return 0;
}
```

Again can some explain what `test[0][0]` is doing because I have no idea and why it runs but `test[0][1]` fails?

Cheers
Dom

Comment: `int* test[10];` declares an array of 10 pointers. These pointers have not been pointed at valid storage, so trying to Read them or write to them is an adventure in the lands of Undefined Behaviour where ANYTHING can happen.

Comment: A short answer is there is only one value in test which is 5 the first value so [0][0] = 5, there is no other value store after that so [0][1] will give seg fault

Comment: Hi why does [0][0] give 5? I thought the syntax was *test[0] ? Cheers Dom

Comment: I'm afraid that's not correct, @Xion. There is no valid `[0][0]` either. It's only through dumb luck and the magic of undefined behaviour that `*(test[0]) = 5;` stored a 5 where it could be read back.

Comment: If p is a pointer to a non-void type, then _*p and p[0]_ are exactly equivalent.  So is _*(p+1) and p[1]_,  _*(p+2) and p[2]_, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Already the first part

```
int* test[10];
*(test[0]) = 5;
```

is undefined behaviour, because you dereference an uninitialized pointer value.

Explanation:

- `int* test[10]` is an array of 10 pointers to ints, each pointer
  being not initialized and definitely not pointing to a memory that
  you reserved to store ints.
- `test[0]` gives an uninitialized pointer; already this statement is
  UB
- `*(test[0]) = 5` dereferences an arbitrary pointer value, definitely
  UB

Try:

```
int* test[10];
int  firstLine[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
test[0] = firstLine;
cout << test[0][0]; // gives 1, firstLine[0]
cout << test[0][1]; // gives 2, is the same as firstLine[1]
// cout << test[1][0]; // undefined behaviour, the second pointer in array test is not initialized
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I think it's the first line that I struggle with because int* test[10] looks like it test is array of 10 pointers to ints but it's an array of pointers to an array of ints. is the syntax the same for both cases?

Comment: `int *x` is a pointer to a single int or a pointer to the first of a sequence of ints, it's the same. Similarily, `int test[10]` is an array of 10 such pointers, each pointing either to a single int or to the first one in a sequence of ints.

Answer (score 1):

C++ permits the use of array notation `[` `]` when dereferencing a pointer.

In the simplest case, you can say something like:

```
char *ptr = new char[10];
```

That creates a pointer to char, which points to the first character in an array of ten characters allocated with `new[]`.

After doing this:

```
char ch = *ptr;
```

and

```
char ch = ptr[0];
```

do the exact same thing.  However since there are 10 characters in the array, you can also say:

```
char ch5 = ptr[5];
```

to access an element further up the array.

This leads to an eqivalence in C++ (and C, where it originated) that:

```
ptr[x];
```

is identical to:

```
*(ptr + x);
```

for any pointer / array referenced by `ptr` and any index `x`.

Comment: Also, `x[ptr]` :)

Comment: True, however since the OP is a new poster, I purposely left out that construction since it's likely to cause confusion, and do more harm than good.  I fully agree that it is technically correct, but at the same time there is wisdom (in my extremely humble opinion) in avoiding it in production code simply as a means to help keep the code clear and easily understood.